# Erro ao executar .jar fora do eclipse com javaFX

Tags: javafx

Estou tentando executar um `.jar` fora do *eclipse* e está retornando o seguinte **ERRO**:

> C:\Risc>java -jar GraphicalReport.jar
>   Exception in Application start method
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
>   der.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
>   urce)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(
>   Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
>   at br.ind.risc.application.ReportMain.initRootLayout(ReportMain.java:59)
>   at br.ind.risc.application.ReportMain.start(ReportMain.java:46)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162
>   (Unknown Source)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown
>   Source)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Sourc
>   e)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown S
>   ource)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)

**Método init.**

```
/**
 * inicializa o layout
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        loader.setLocation(ReportMain.class.getResource(" /br/ind/risc/view/RootLayout.fxml"));

        rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load(); //o erro está aqui.

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao que parece ele não está encontrando o arquivo "***/br/ind/risc/view/RootLayout.fxml***". Sugiro abrir o arquivo .jar e verificar se o fxml está lá. Outra coisa existe um espaço no começo do caminho informado é isso mesmo?

O ideal é que os arquivos de layout(fxml) fiquem dentro da pasta **resources** do projeto. Verifique isso também.

De uma olhada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228487/javafx-location-is-not-set-error-message. Me parece um problema parecido.

Segue os passos:

1) Mova principal classe para o padrão pacote

2) Coloque outro caminho para o Eclipse, e outra durante a execução do arquivo JAR (cole isso em Main.java )

```
public  static  final  String sourcePath = isProgramRunnedFromJar ()  ?  "src/"  :  "" ; 
public  static  boolean isProgramRunnedFromJar ()  { 
    File x = getCurrentJarFileLocation (); 
    if ( x . getAbsolutePath (). contains ( "target" + File . separator + "classes" )){ 
        return  false ; 
    }  else  { 
        return  true ; 
    } 
} 
public  static  File getCurrentJarFileLocation ()  { 
        try  { 
            return  new  File ( Main . class . getProtectionDomain (). getCodeSource (). getLocation (). toURI (). getPath ()); 
        }  catch ( URISyntaxException e ){ 
            e . printStackTrace (); 
            return  null ; 
        } 
}
```

E depois disso no início do método que você tem que carregar arquivos como este:

```
FXMLLoader loader =  new  FXMLLoader ( getClass (). GetResource ( sourcePath + "MainScene.fxml" ));
```